# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"034545104X"' Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, literals

```
ratings["isbn"] = ratings["isbn"].astype(int)
```

I am getting this error when trying to convert the column into integer format for analysis. I even tried to replace the quotation marks and X from the isbn column. Even then I am getting the error.

```
ratings_data['isbn'] = ratings_data['isbn'].replace({'"':''}, regex=True)
ratings_data['isbn'] = ratings_data['isbn'].replace({'X':''}, regex=True)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Even then I am getting the error.` - there is another error? Repalce working well for you?

Comment: I have downloaded the data from http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~cziegler/BX/. Replace is working well but the error exists even after using it.

Comment: So how shoul;d be processed `'B0000BLD7'` ?

Comment: @jezrael As far as I checked the ISBN is masked with X where the digits are not available. I didn't get any values like 'B0000BLD7'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is there is many another strings like `X`, you can find all `ISBN` non only ends with `X` and no numeric:

```
ratings_data = pd.read_csv('BX-Book-Ratings.csv', sep=';')
# print(ratings_data.head(10))

df = ratings_data[~ratings_data['ISBN'].str.contains(r'^\d+$|^\d+X$')]
print(df)
         User-ID           ISBN  Book-Rating
54        276762     B0000BLD7X            0
55        276762    N3453124715            4
384       276884     B158991965            6
535       276929  2.02.032126.2            0
536       276929  2.264.03602.8            0
         ...            ...          ...
1146393   275970     014014904x            0
1147650   276009    01400.77022            0
1147916   276046     08348OO799           10
1148549   276331   \0432534220"            9
1149066   276556     055337849x           10

[3092 rows x 3 columns]
```

Possible solution is filter only data with `X` or numeric for processing:

```
ratings_data = pd.read_csv('BX-Book-Ratings.csv', sep=';')
# print(ratings_data.head(10))

ratings_data = ratings_data[ratings_data['ISBN'].str.contains(r'^\d+$|^\d+X$')]
print(ratings_data)
         User-ID         ISBN  Book-Rating
0         276725   034545104X            0
1         276726   0155061224            5
2         276727   0446520802            0
3         276729   052165615X            3
4         276729   0521795028            6
         ...          ...          ...
1149775   276704   1563526298            9
1149776   276706   0679447156            0
1149777   276709   0515107662           10
1149778   276721   0590442449           10
1149779   276723  05162443314            8

[1146688 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

```
ratings_data['ISBN'] = ratings_data['ISBN'].replace({'X':''}, regex=True).astype(np.int64)
print(ratings_data)
         User-ID        ISBN  Book-Rating
0         276725    34545104            0
1         276726   155061224            5
2         276727   446520802            0
3         276729    52165615            3
4         276729   521795028            6
         ...         ...          ...
1149775   276704  1563526298            9
1149776   276706   679447156            0
1149777   276709   515107662           10
1149778   276721   590442449           10
1149779   276723  5162443314            8

[1146688 rows x 3 columns]
```